# How do I vertically center text?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on getting the text in my content div centered vertically and I'm stumped. The container includes 1 div with a title and 1 div with content.

I've tried elements such as:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

and also playing with the displays/positioning, but I'm not having any luck.

The current CSS is the following:

```
.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: left;
  -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
  transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: #f0f7fc;
}
```

Comment: The flex version centers the content vertically, but it also centers it horizontally. I need to left align the text in a vertically centered container.

Comment: If you use flex, then why not have a look into what the properties mean so that you understand how it works, you can easily vertically center the with the text been left aligned

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Flexbox

[Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) allows you to vertically align the text without having a `div` with a fixed `height`. It is now supported by all the modern browsers.

[Check my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979702/display-flex-not-working-on-internet-explorer/43979973#43979973) to see all the problems and workarounds for Flexbox. The majority are for Internet Explorer.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Test
</div>
```

## `line-height`

If you know the `height` of the external `div`, you can use [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

```
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px; /* same value as height */
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Test
</div>
```

## `display: table-cell`

`display: table-cell` is another good alternative which allows you to vertically align without knowing the height of the `div`. It works in older browsers too ([except Internet Explorer 7](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)).

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Test
</div>
```