# display: flex not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My flex container:

```
.back_pattern {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

On other browsers everything works.
ie11 : http://take.ms/68dHo ;
chrome : http://take.ms/JhcEH
What's problem?

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more of your code? For example the html and the css?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't fully support [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) due to:

> Partial support is due to large amount of bugs present (see known
> issues).

[image]
<sub>Screenshot and infos taken from [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)</sub>

### Notes

Internet Explorer before 10 doesn't support Flexbox, while IE 11 only supports the [2012 syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/).

### Known issues

- IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property see MSFT documentation.
- In IE10 and IE11, containers with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has `min-height` but no explicit `height` property. [See bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview).
- In IE10 the default value for `flex` is `0 0 auto` rather than `0 1 auto` as defined in the latest spec.
- IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when `min-height` is used. [See bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/816293/ie11-flexbox-with-min-height-not-vertically-aligning-with-align-items-center).

### Workarounds

[Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) is a community-curated list of Flexbox issues and cross-browser workarounds for them. Here's a list of all the bugs with a workaround available and the browsers that affect.

1. [Minimum content sizing of flex items not honored](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-1)
2. [Column flex items set to `align-items: center` overflow their container](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-2)
3. [`min-height` on a flex container won't apply to its flex items](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3)
4. [`flex` shorthand declarations with unitless `flex-basis` values are ignored](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-4)
5. [Column `flex` items don't always preserve intrinsic aspect ratios](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-5)
6. [The default flex value has changed](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-6)
7. [`flex-basis` doesn't account for `box-sizing: border-box`](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-7)
8. [`flex-basis` doesn't support `calc()`](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-8)
9. [Some HTML elements can't be flex containers](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9)
10. [`align-items: baseline` doesn't work with nested flex containers](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-10)
11. [Min and max size declarations are ignored when wrapping flex items](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-11)
12. [Inline elements are not treated as flex-items](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-12)
13. [Importance is ignored on flex-basis when using flex shorthand](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-13)
14. [Shrink-to-fit containers with `flex-flow: column wrap` do not contain their items](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-14)
15. [Column flex items ignore `margin: auto` on the cross axis](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-15)
16. [`flex-basis` cannot be animated](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-16)
17. [Flex items are not correctly justified when `max-width` is used](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-17)

Answer (score 1):

Am afraid this question has been answered a few times, Pls take a look at the following if it's related

- [Flexbox and Internet Explorer 11 (display:flex in <html>?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600345/flexbox-and-internet-explorer-11-displayflex-in-html)
- [Flexbox not working in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905749/flexbox-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)